# OpenCart 3 custom module doesn't save data

Tags: php, twig, opencart-module, opencart-3

Im developing a payment module for OpenCart 3. Since there's no updater documentation my module is based on the others payment module (such as Alipay, paypal, cash on demand, etc....)

I've created the module view on admin/view/template/extension/payment/mipago.twig as simply

```
{{ header }}{{ column_left }}
{% if error_warning %}
    {{ error_warning }}
{% endif %}
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" form="form-mipago" data-toggle="tooltip" title={{ button_save }} class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
        <a href={{ cancel }} data-toggle="tooltip" title={{ button_cancel }} class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div>
      <h1>{{ heading_title }}</h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        {% for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
            <li><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    {% if error_warning %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>{{ error_warning }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>{{ text_edit }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="{{ action }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-mipago" class="form-horizontal">


               <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-status">{{ entry_status }}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select name="mipago_status" id="input-status" class="form-control">
                            {% if paygol_status %}
                            <option value="1" selected="selected">{{ text_enabled }}</option>
                            <option value="0">{{ text_disabled }}</option>
                            {% else %}
                            <option value="1">{{ text_enabled}}</option>
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">{{ text_disabled }}</option>
                            {% endif %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{ footer }}
```

And the controller admin/controller/extension/payment/mipago.php

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionPaymentMiPago extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->document->setTitle('Mi Pago');

        $this->load->model('setting/setting');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('payment_mipago', $this->request->post);

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=payment', true));
        }

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = "'';
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => 'Inicio',
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true)
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => 'Extensiones',
            'href' => $this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=payment', true)
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => 'Mi Pago',
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/payment/mipago', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true)
        );

        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/payment/mipago', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true);

        $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=payment', true);

        if (isset($this->request->post['mipago_status'])) {
            $data['mipago_status'] = $this->request->post['mipago_status'];
        } else {
            $data['mipago_status'] = $this->config->get('mipago_status');
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['paygol_order_status_id'])) {
            $data['mipago_order_status_id'] = $this->request->post['mipago_order_status_id'];
        } else {
            $data['mipago_order_status_id'] = $this->config->get('mipago_order_status_id');
        }

        $this->load->model('localisation/order_status');
        $data['order_statuses'] = $this->model_localisation_order_status->getOrderStatuses();

        if (isset($this->request->post['mipago_geo_zone_id'])) {
            $data['mipago_geo_zone_id'] = $this->request->post['mipago_geo_zone_id'];
        } else {
            $data['mipago_geo_zone_id'] = $this->config->get('mipago_geo_zone_id');
        }

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/payment/mipago', $data));
    }

    protected function validate() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/payment/mipago')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }
        return !$this->error;
    }
}
```

This is a mockup but the problem its present, I cannot save the data from the form on the view. My code is based on other payment modules such as G2APay and Cash on Demand but even using the same lines of code (only changing the parameters) it doesnt save anything.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

It was just a mismatch between the module name, it's type and all the variables and fields.

For example, my plugin needs to be a `payment` module, so all the variables should be be named `payment_mipago_<field>`, instead of `mipago_<field>`, including the fields that opencart inserts to the database

Answer (score 0):

For OC3.0 should be:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['payment_mipago_status'])) {
            $data['payment_mipago_status'] = $this->request->post['payment_mipago_status'];
        } else {
            $data['payment_mipago_status'] = $this->config->get('payment_mipago_status');
        }
```

and for all variables you must add `payment`