# Opencart 3.0 does not save data custom module

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I have a shipping module for Opencart 3.0.0.0. And I dont understand why module data does not save.

For example, login field in admin/controller/extension/shipping/onedelivery.php:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['shipping_onedelivery_login'])) {
        $data['shipping_onedelivery_login'] = $this->request->post['shipping_onedelivery_login'];
    } else {
        $data['shipping_onedelivery_login'] = $this->config->get('shipping_onedelivery_login');
    }
```

action route:

```
$data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/shipping/onedelivery', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], 'SSL');
```

this field in view (admin/view/template/extension/shipping/onedelivery.twig

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="shipping_onedelivery_login">{{ entry_onedelivery_login }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="shipping_onedelivery_login" value="{{ shipping_onedelivery_login }}" placeholder="{{ shipping_onedelivery_login }}" id="shipping_onedelivery_login" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
```

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042257/opencart-3-custom-module-doesnt-save-data) did not solve my problem. I renamed fields.
I make same module for opencart 2.0 and 2.3 and everything was fine.
Whats wrong? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Showed in database that code (first parameter in method editSetting) must be like shipping_.